# trigonometric inequality - how to prove it?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

Let $ 0 < x < \frac {\pi}{2}$

How to prove it?
$$2 \sin x \le x- \frac {\pi}{3} + \sqrt {3} $$

Comment: Have you tried anything? Think of how you can bound $2\sin{x}$ on the given interval, and while the $\sqrt{3}$ may look out of place, think about when $2\sin{x}$ equals $\sqrt{3}$. Also think about characteristics of $\sin{x}$ on that interval; in particular, its derivative.

Comment: I was sooo blind!
It's trivial $2 sinx - 2 sin \frac{\pi}{3} ≤x −  \frac{\pi}{3}$  aaand 
sin x ≤ x
Thanks :)

Comment: Careful: while $2(\sin{x} - \sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}) \le x - \frac{\pi}{3}$ is correct, and $\sin{x} \le x$ is correct, the left hand side of the inequality involves $2\sin{x}$. However, you can still do a bounding argument. [Plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282sin%28x%29-2sin%28pi/3%29%29%20-%20%28x-pi/3%29) the difference may help if you need further insight.

Comment: I see what you mean. But in this case my range is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a standard *mechanical* approach. (But mechanical is often not best.) Let
$$f(x)=x-\frac{\pi}{3}+\sqrt{3} -2\sin x.$$
Then $f'(x)=1-2\cos x$.

The derivative is negative until $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$, that is, until $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, and then is positive.

So $f(x)$ reaches a minimum in our interval at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Evaluate $f(\pi/3)$. We get $0$. So in our interval, $f(x)\ge 0$, with equality only at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I correct understand this method. 
I just need to check, where my function is bigger than 0. (with derivatives) If it is always positive in my range then inequality is ok. If there is any point ≤0 then inequality is false. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Note that $a\le b$ if and only if $b-a\ge 0$. Here is another example. We show that $\sin x\le x$ if $x\ge 0$. Let $f(x)=x-\sin x$. Then $f(0)=0$, and $f'(x)=1-\cos x\ge 0$, so $f$ is increasing, and therefore is $\gt 0$ if $x\gt 0$. Now show $\cos x\ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$, say for $x\ge 0$. Let $g(x)=\cos x-(1-\frac{x^2}{2})$. We have $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=-\sin x+x\ge 0$ by the previous result, so $g(x)$ is increasing, and the inequality follows. A very useful technique.